# How to resolve conflict between two choices starting with same tokens in javacc

Tags: compiler-construction, lexer, javacc

I'm trying to write a compiler for some specific format of messages. 
My problem if I simplify it is:

```
< WORD : ([LETTER]){2,5}>
< ANOTHER_WORD : (<LETTER>|<DIGIT>){1,5}>
< SPECIAL_WORLD : "START">

void grammar():
{
}
{ 
 <WORD><ANOTHER_WORD>
| <SPECIAL_WORD><ANOTHER_WORD>
}
```

Here my special word is matched always as a WORD which is logical of course but since the conflict is at the beginning of the production I don't know how to resolve it.
some help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the first line, should `[LETTER]` be `<LETTER>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the rule for `START` first. Like most lexical scanner generators, JavaCC uses the rule that the longest possible token match is selected, and then, if two or more patterns apply, the first of these is chosen.

As a result, you `ANOTHER_WORD` rule will only match if `WORD` doesn't, so that it will only match words of length 1 or which contain a digit.

It appears that you expect the parser state to affect how lexical tokens are recognized. That's not how lexical scanners work, in general, but you can implement a limited form of contextual scanning by using [lexical states](https://javacc.java.net/doc/javaccgrm.html#newprod1).

Comment: thanks, changing the order actually solved this problem (but created another ambiguity with another token)