# How to resolve conflict in choice in multiple choices case that have the same token

Tags: compiler-construction, lexer, javacc

I'm trying to write a compiler for some specific format of messages. My problem now since i'm building different formats of specific messages is described like this

```
< WORD : ([LETTER]){2,5}>
< ANOTHER_WORD : (<LETTER>|<DIGIT>){1,5}>
< SPECIAL_WORLD_EN : "START">
< SPECIAL_WORLD_FR : "COMMENCER">
< SPECIAL_END_WORLD_EN : "END">
< SPECIAL_END_WORLD_FR : "FIN">
< LEFT_BRACKET : "[">
< RIGHT_BRACKET : "]">
void grammar():
{
}
{ 
LOOKAHEAD(2)
 <LEFT_BRACKET><SPECIAL_WORLD_EN>< WORD ><RIGHT_PAREN>
| <LEFT_BRACKET><SPECIAL_WORLD_FR>< WORD >< ANOTHER_WORD ><RIGHT_BRACKET>
| <LEFT_BRACKET><SPECIAL_END_WORLD_EN>(< WORD >)?<RIGHT_BRACKET>
| <LEFT_BRACKET><SPECIAL_END_WORLD_FR>(< WORD >)+<RIGHT_BRACKET>
}
```

So the LOOKAHEAD(2) solves the conflict for the first two choices.
How can I solve the conflict for the other choices
( in the real grammar I have more than 4 choices)

**UPDATE**
I managed to remove the choice conflict warning by using a LOOKAHEAD(2) in each choice

```
void grammar():
{
}
{ 
LOOKAHEAD(2)
 <LEFT_BRACKET><SPECIAL_WORLD_EN>< WORD ><RIGHT_PAREN>
| LOOKAHEAD(2) <LEFT_BRACKET><SPECIAL_WORLD_FR>< WORD >< ANOTHER_WORD ><RIGHT_BRACKET>
| LOOKAHEAD(2) <LEFT_BRACKET><SPECIAL_END_WORLD_EN>(< WORD >)?<RIGHT_BRACKET>
| LOOKAHEAD(2) <LEFT_BRACKET><SPECIAL_END_WORLD_FR>(< WORD >)+<RIGHT_BRACKET>
}
```

I'm not sure it's the best solution, is there any other better/correct way to resolve it?

Comment: You've still not fixed your lexical problem described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008283/how-to-resolve-conflict-between-two-choices-starting-with-same-tokens-in-javacc

Comment: well it's fixed, but still have somes problems like this one for exemple.

Comment: In the production for `WORD`, should `[LETTER]` be `<LETTER>`?

Comment: You have two sorts of problem.  You have a parsing problem.  The solution to that is below.  You also have a lexical problem, arising because of the order of your regular expression productions.  The solution to was given in answer to your earlier question.  Unless you fix the lexical grammar the parsing grammar won't work even though it is correct.  Read the FAQ, it is all explained there.

Comment: I have litterally hundreds of tokens that are all specific in their construction. that makes it hard to order them. Can this ambiguity be fixed if I change lexical state? ( Defining a custom state for each choice)

Comment: If you want "START", for example, to always be a `SPECIAL_WORD_EN`, it's just a matter of finding the right order. But suppose you want "START" to sometimes behave like a `SPECIAL_WORD_EN` and sometimes like a `WORD`. There are several approaches. Lexical states is one. Three approaches are covered in the FAQ under How do I deal with keywords that aren't reserved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left factor:

```
void grammar():
{ }
{ 
    <LEFT_BRACKET>
    ( <SPECIAL_WORLD_EN>< WORD ><RIGHT_PAREN>
    | <SPECIAL_WORLD_FR>< WORD >< ANOTHER_WORD ><RIGHT_BRACKET>
    | <SPECIAL_END_WORLD_EN>(< WORD >)?<RIGHT_BRACKET>
    | <SPECIAL_END_WORLD_FR>(< WORD >)+<RIGHT_BRACKET> )
 }
```